# Usps not giving shipping service in track response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, usps

I am using following track request

```
http://production.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPITest.dll?API=TrackV2
&XML=<TrackRequest USERID="xxxxxxxx">
<TrackID ID="EJ958088694US"></TrackID></TrackRequest>
```

where i am giving Tracking number of shipment and getting the track response.
But i am not getting the service type in the response.

Example:- For Tracking number `"9400110200830528706282"` not getting service "First Class Mail" in xml response.

Usps site is showing "First Class Mail" as a service for the mentioned tracking number.

Please suggest the track request for getting the shipping method.

Answer (score 1):

Im sure Tracking Api wont return Shippingmethod it just return track id and status, for getting Shipping method you need to handle before printing label, in label you need to mention shipping method then you can use that shipping method
please refer below link for further details.

https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/welcome.htm

Answer (score 0):

This information is available through "TrackFieldRequest"

### Example Request

```
<TrackFieldRequest USERID="xxxxxxxx">
<Revision>1</Revision>
<ClientIp>127.0.0.1</ClientIp>
<SourceId>John Doe</SourceId>
    <TrackID ID="010850921250125054">
        <DestinationZipCode>12345</DestinationZipCode>
        <MailingDate>2010-01-01</MailingDate>
   </TrackID>
</TrackFieldRequest>
```

### Example Request Response

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<TrackResponse>
     <TrackInfo ID="9102969010383081813033">
          <Class>Package Services</Class>
          ...
     </TrackInfo>
</TrackResponse>
```

Source:
https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/track-and-confirm.htm#_Toc378923168